# Combinatorics Question: Alphabet of $16$ letters, $8$ slots, arbitrary blanks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If I have an alphabet of $16$ characters and $8$ slots that are filled with any combination of characters (no duplicates except blanks), how do I calculate the total number of combinations?

Edit for clarification

(using a smile set of 3 char (1-3) and 4 slots (using x as blank or null)

```
xxxx is valid
1xxx is valid
xxx1 is valid
123x is valid
12x3 is valid
3xx3 is not valid
1x1x is not valid
321x is valid
```

I appreciate everyone help I don't have much math background so im struggling to convey the concept with out a proper vocabulary

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more thorough and add some examples of legal/illegal combinations?

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: How is this computer science? What are blanks?

Comment: @user4140, sorry its really not I must have put that in by accident I am however using it for a program that I am running

Comment: @newb yes it does

Comment: @ragnar, as a simplified example (were going to say 10 char (0-9) 8 slots and x is null or blank or empty however you want to put it)  so xxxxxxxx is valid xxxxxxx1 is valid 1xxxxxx is valid  (1x1xxxx is not) 12xxxxxx is valid xxxxx12 is valid does that help?

Answer (score 2):

OP didn't mention whether order matters or doesn't matter. So here is an answer for either case:

**Order Doesn't Matter**

You have an alphabet of $16$ characters and you have $8$ slots to be filled. Then the number of combinations is ${16 \choose 8}$.

However, you are allowed to use blanks. So suppose you use one blank. Then we have $7$ slots to be filled: that's ${16 \choose 7}$. The same goes for two blanks: we have ${16 \choose 6}$.

So the total number of possible combinations will be, by the rule of sum, ${16 \choose 8} + {16 \choose 7} + \ldots + {16 \choose 1}$, or in summation notation: $$\sum_{i=1}^{8} {16 \choose i}$$

**Order Matters**

Again, you have $8$ slots to be filled. There are ${16 \choose 8}$ ways to choose the elements. Now you have to order them. For $n$ distinct objects, there are $n!$ permutations. As we will always have $8$ objects, the total number of ways to fill $8$ slots is ${16 \choose 8} \cdot 8!$.

Now take the case with $1$ blank. There are ${16 \choose 7}$ ways to choose the elements. Now, notice that the blank space also counts a distinct element. In this case, we have ${16 \choose 7} \cdot 8!$ combinations.

Now take the case with $2$ blanks. We have ${16 \choose 6}$ ways to choose the elements. We have two blank spaces --- they only count as one distinct element. So we have ${16 \choose 6} \cdot 7!$ combinations. Etc.

So the total number of possible combination, again by the sum rule, will be ${16 \choose 8}8! + {16 \choose 7}8! + {16 \choose 6}7! + {16 \choose 5}6! + \ldots + {16 \choose 1}2!$. I suppose an adequate closed-form expression would be: $${16 \choose 8}8! + {\sum_{i=1}^{7}{{16 \choose i}(i+1)!}}$$

Comment: Thanks, In this case all 8 slots can be blank

Comment: @Crash893 Then in both cases you just need to add 1 to account for that possibility.

Comment: @newb do you allow for different positions for the blank in your solution?

Comment: @user4140 the blanks are indistinguishable, and yes.

Comment: But don't the blanks have to be together in your solution?

Comment: @user4140 why would the blanks have to be contiguous? I see no such indication.

Comment: you say they only count as one element so then there are 7! combinations.

Comment: @user4140 that's because we have two blanks, and they are indistinguishable. For example, if you try to put $8$ indistinguishable items into $8$ buckets, there's only $1$ way to do it.

Comment: What about ordering 2 x and one y? how many ways?

Comment: `y__, _y_, __y`: three.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters. Then for $n$ blanks you need to chose the n blanks in $\binom{8}{n}$ ways and then choose a permutation of the 8-n characters in $\frac{16!}{(8+n)!}$ ways. So the total number of words is $\sum_{n=0}^8 \frac{16!}{(8+n)!}\binom{8}{n}$